# NullReferenceException at random rows using Google Maps API

Tags: c#, sql, xml, google-maps

I am getting a kind of weird exception. I do the following:
Get streetname, number and city from a SQL Server Database.
I read the outcome with a `SqlDataReader` and I insert it in the URL for the Google Maps API.

Next I load it into an XML Document and get the values for longitude and latitude.

I all works fine, but it never finishes. There are 417 distinct rows. Sometimes it gives a `NullReferenceException` at the 25th-ish row, and sometimes at the 300th-ish row.

```
public void calcLatLong(SqlCommand sql)
    {
        sql.Connection = connection;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
        String finalread = "";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            finalread = reader[0] + "" + reader[1] + "" + reader[2];

            //URL for using Google API
            String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + finalread + "&sensor=false";
            //XML format for scraping webpage
            XmlDocument objXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            objXmlDocument.Load(url);

            latitude = objXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()").Value;
            longitude = objXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng/text()").Value;
            Console.Write(latitude + " ");

Console.WriteLine(longitude);
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

The error message is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

At this line:

```
latitude = objXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()").Value;
```

But it is this line, because that's the first line to select something from the URL.

I think it might be the Wireless Network. I tried to `ping` google.com via `cmd.exe` a hundred times and it lost one packet. So that would instantly give an error, right?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the whole error message? It would help to see the line number where the error is being thrown at, or the object involved in the error, etc. I have a strong feeling that the problem is with the data that you are retrieving.

Comment: I added it. My guess is that the URL does not get loaded properly. That's why the first line after the `objXmlDocument.Load(url);` returns a `null` value.
But that's just my guess.

Comment: Ok, then I'm sure what's null is the value of that node in your xml. What you should do is try to break at that line at the point in execution when the error would be thrown and try to see what the XML looks like. If the xml has a node like the one you are looking for and its value is not null, then something else is wrong, but if the node is null then you are creating your xml wrong and if the value is null, then all you have to do is put in some logic to handle your values being null because that means you have a null value in your database.

Comment: But the value of the String is never `null`, unless it gets returned `null`.

If I ping (in this case google.com) then sometimes is gives a 500+ ms response. I do not know if this affects it?

I do not think my XML loading is fault, since it gives the exception at random values.

Comment: That is definitely a long ping, but I am certain that your problem is with your xml at least to some degree since that is what the line you posted is erroring out on.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't it be that the response time was too long and that it loaded nothing? Or would that end up in an HTTP error?

Comment: If the response time was too long, I don't think you would get this far in the execution and the code would have errored out at this line "objXmlDocument.Load(url);." Can you post the url that you are trying to load and/or the xml document that you are trying to query?

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=[address]&sensor=false

Insert address in [address]

Comment: I need to know what address equals.